# java regex escape sequences

Tags: java, regex

I was wondering about regex in Java and stumbled upon the use of backslashes. For instance, if I wanted to look for occurences of the words "this regex" in a text, I would do something like this:

`Pattern.compile("this regex");`

Nonetheless, I could also do something like this:

`Pattern.compile("this\\sregex");`

My question is: what is the difference between the two of them? And why do I have to type the backslash twice, I mean, why isn't \s an escape sequence in Java? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `\s` means any whitespace character, including tab, line feed and carriage return.
2. Java string literals already use `\` to escape special characters. To put the character `\` in a string literal, you need to write `"\\"`. However regex patterns also use `\` as their escape character, and the way to put that into a string literal is to use two, because it goes through two separate escaping processes. If you read your regex pattern from a plain text file for example, you won't need double escaping.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you need two backslashes is that when you enter a regex string in Java code you are actually dealing with two parsers:

- The first is the Java compiler, which is converting your string literal to a Java String.
- The second is the regex parser, which is interpreting your regex, after it has been converted to a Java string and then passed to the regex parse when you call `Pattern.compile`.

So when you input `"this\\sregex"`, it will be converted to the Java string `"this\sregex"` by the Java compiler. Then when you call `Pattern.compile` with the string, the backslash will be interpreted by the regex compiler as a special character.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that \s denotes a whitespace character, which can be more than just a blank space. It can be a tab, newline, line feed, to name a few.