# What is the difference between \d and \\d in regular expression in Java?

Tags: java, regex, string

I'm trying to understand the difference between `\d` and `\\d` in regular expression. I have a quiz that I got wrong, please refer this to answer the question as well.

[image: quiz]

Comment: I wouldn't say that this is a dupe of the referenced Q, but I'm sure there's an A explaining it on SA (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/30262198/2064981). The problem is that the RE is defined in a string, and in java ``\`` needs to be escaped in a string, to represent a literal ``\ ``. I.e. answer **a** is wrong.

Comment: Actually, `b` is also wrong as it requires at least 2 digits after the 2 letters. Flag the question.